mutate() over several different subsets using the same function and naming convention
I have a very wide data frame and some named subsets:
df <-  data.frame(matrix(ncol = 200, nrow = 200))
df <- as.data.frame(
                    apply(df, 1, function(x){return(sample(c(1,2,NA), size = 200, replace = TRUE))})
                    )

xHappy <- c("V22", "V39", "V17", "V2")
xSad <- c("V15", "V11", "V79", "V90", "V80", "V101")
xSilly <- c("V20", "V112")

For each subset, I want to create a new variable counts the number NAs from that subset per row.
I could copy-paste the same method three times:
df.new <- df %>% mutate(
                        missingHappy = rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(xHappy))
                        missingSad = rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(xSad))
                        missingSilly = rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(xSilly))
                        )

But my real data has thousands of variables and dozens of subsets, so this gets both tedious and dangerous and I would really prefer something more concise.
Is there a way I can instead just make a saved mutate() method where all I have to do is call something like makeNAColumns(xSad, xHappy, XSilly) or even df %>% mutate [insert magic one liner]?

You could do this using the purrr package. As @Andre Wildberg stated, as the subs object is a named list, this can be achieved more succinctly than my original answer by using map():
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(42) # for reproducibility
df <-  data.frame(matrix(ncol = 200, nrow = 200))
df <- as.data.frame(
  apply(df, 1, function(x){return(sample(c(1,2,NA), size = 200, replace = TRUE))})
)

xHappy <- c("V22", "V39", "V17", "V2")
xSad <- c("V15", "V11", "V79", "V90", "V80", "V101")
xSilly <- c("V20", "V112")

# Either manually create list of your subset vectors and define output column names
# if they do not share a common name pattern;
subs <- list(
  missingHappy = xHappy,
  missingSad = xSad,
  missingSilly = xSilly
)

# or if all your subset vectors start with x (or have another common pattern)
# return names of all vectors starting with x (or edit to match another pattern)
vnames <- ls(pattern = "^x")

# mget() values for each vector in vnames and rename  
subs <- setNames(mget(vnames), paste0("missing", sub("^x", "", vnames)))

# Apply rowSums across each list in subs, bind_cols() to output
df.new <- bind_cols(df, map(subs, ~ rowSums(is.na(df[.x]))))

head(df.new[,c("V22", "V39", "V17", "V2","V15",
               "V11", "V79", "V90", "V80", "V101",
               "V20", "V112", "missingHappy", "missingSad","missingSilly")])

#   V22 V39 V17 V2 V15 V11 V79 V90 V80 V101 V20 V112 missingHappy missingSad missingSilly
# 1   1   1   1  2   1   2   1   1  NA   NA   1    1            0          2            0
# 2   1  NA  NA NA  NA   1   1  NA   2    2   2    1            3          2            0
# 3  NA   1   1 NA   2   1   1   1  NA    2   2    1            2          1            0
# 4  NA   2  NA NA   1   2   2  NA   2    1   2   NA            3          1            1
# 5   1   2  NA  1   2   2   2   1  NA   NA   1    2            1          2            0
# 6   1   1   2  1  NA   1   1  NA   2   NA   2    2            0          3            0


Since there's already a named list you can simply use map on subs.

@AndreWildberg - thanks for that,  will update answer accordingly.

Also doesn't need set_names this way. The advantage of the named list ;)

@AndreWildberg - ah, yes. Your help is most appreciated.

I tried your code, but when I got to df.new <- bind_cols(df, map(subs, ~ rowSums(is.na(df[.x])))) it throws "error in map(): In index: 1. With name: missing. Caused by error in [,data.frame: ! undefined columns selected

@purpleblade98 - given this works on the sample df and subset vectors you provided, I'm assuming you mean it does not work on your actual data? The error is most likely caused by a column name in one of your subset vectors not existing in your df. Double-check you have your column names listed correctly in xHappy etc. To check, you can run unlist(subs, use.names = FALSE) %in% names(df) and see if any return false.
